# PyQt: Editable QTabWidget tab text

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, qtabwidget

I can rename tab label programmatically.

With `QInputDialog` I can get new label text and set tab widget label.

But, I hope for a more user-friendly solution like double-clicking on label and get editing on the tab itself.

A `QListWidgetItem` with editable flag can show me the way, but I can't find the solution for tab label.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are no built-in methods for achieving this. However, you could use a simple popup line-edit and position it over the tab. Here's a basic demo script:

[image]

**PyQt5**:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets

class TabBar(QtWidgets.QTabBar):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self._editor = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self)
        self._editor.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.Popup)
        self._editor.setFocusProxy(self)
        self._editor.editingFinished.connect(self.handleEditingFinished)
        self._editor.installEventFilter(self)

    def eventFilter(self, widget, event):
        if ((event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.MouseButtonPress and
             not self._editor.geometry().contains(event.globalPos())) or
            (event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.KeyPress and
             event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_Escape)):
            self._editor.hide()
            return True
        return super().eventFilter(widget, event)

    def mouseDoubleClickEvent(self, event):
        index = self.tabAt(event.pos())
        if index >= 0:
            self.editTab(index)

    def editTab(self, index):
        rect = self.tabRect(index)
        self._editor.setFixedSize(rect.size())
        self._editor.move(self.parent().mapToGlobal(rect.topLeft()))
        self._editor.setText(self.tabText(index))
        if not self._editor.isVisible():
            self._editor.show()

    def handleEditingFinished(self):
        index = self.currentIndex()
        if index >= 0:
            self._editor.hide()
            self.setTabText(index, self._editor.text())

class Window(QtWidgets.QTabWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setTabBar(TabBar(self))
        self.addTab(QtWidgets.QWidget(self), 'Tab One')
        self.addTab(QtWidgets.QWidget(self), 'Tab Two')

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.setWindowTitle('Test')
    window.setGeometry(600, 100, 200, 100)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**PyQt4**:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class TabBar(QtGui.QTabBar):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        QtGui.QTabBar.__init__(self, parent)
        self._editor = QtGui.QLineEdit(self)
        self._editor.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.Popup)
        self._editor.setFocusProxy(self)
        self._editor.editingFinished.connect(self.handleEditingFinished)
        self._editor.installEventFilter(self)

    def eventFilter(self, widget, event):
        if ((event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.MouseButtonPress and
             not self._editor.geometry().contains(event.globalPos())) or
            (event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.KeyPress and
             event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_Escape)):
            self._editor.hide()
            return True
        return QtGui.QTabBar.eventFilter(self, widget, event)

    def mouseDoubleClickEvent(self, event):
        index = self.tabAt(event.pos())
        if index >= 0:
            self.editTab(index)

    def editTab(self, index):
        rect = self.tabRect(index)
        self._editor.setFixedSize(rect.size())
        self._editor.move(self.parent().mapToGlobal(rect.topLeft()))
        self._editor.setText(self.tabText(index))
        if not self._editor.isVisible():
            self._editor.show()

    def handleEditingFinished(self):
        index = self.currentIndex()
        if index >= 0:
            self._editor.hide()
            self.setTabText(index, self._editor.text())

class Window(QtGui.QTabWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QTabWidget.__init__(self)
        self.setTabBar(TabBar(self))
        self.addTab(QtGui.QWidget(self), 'Tab One')
        self.addTab(QtGui.QWidget(self), 'Tab Two')

if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.setWindowTitle('Test')
    window.setGeometry(600, 100, 200, 100)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: WOW!!!! YOU ARE MY SAVIOR!! Thank you for your kindness. It works! I pasted your script, edit a little ;) , and just do "setTabBar"

Comment: Excellent solution!

Answer (score 5):

Update to the answer left by ekhumoro :

In PyQt5, the code now looks like this :

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QEvent
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QTabBar, QTabWidget, QApplication, QLineEdit, QWidget

class EditableTabBar(QTabBar):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        QTabBar.__init__(self, parent)
        self._editor = QLineEdit(self)
        self._editor.setWindowFlags(Qt.Popup)
        self._editor.setFocusProxy(self)
        self._editor.editingFinished.connect(self.handleEditingFinished)
        self._editor.installEventFilter(self)

    def eventFilter(self, widget, event):
        if ((event.type() == QEvent.MouseButtonPress and not self._editor.geometry().contains(event.globalPos())) or (event.type() == QEvent.KeyPress and event.key() == Qt.Key_Escape)):
            self._editor.hide()
            return True
        return QTabBar.eventFilter(self, widget, event)

    def mouseDoubleClickEvent(self, event):
        index = self.tabAt(event.pos())
        if index >= 0:
            self.editTab(index)

    def editTab(self, index):
        rect = self.tabRect(index)
        self._editor.setFixedSize(rect.size())
        self._editor.move(self.parent().mapToGlobal(rect.topLeft()))
        self._editor.setText(self.tabText(index))
        if not self._editor.isVisible():
            self._editor.show()

    def handleEditingFinished(self):
        index = self.currentIndex()
        if index >= 0:
            self._editor.hide()
            self.setTabText(index, self._editor.text())

class Window(QTabWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QTabWidget.__init__(self)
        self.setTabBar(EditableTabBar(self))
        self.addTab(QWidget(self), 'Tab One')
        self.addTab(QWidget(self), 'Tab Two')

if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: On pyside2, I had to change the event filter return to `super().eventFilter(widget, event)`, as the qlineedit cursor would become invisible otherwise. The top answer provides this fix already.